# i'm facing some ValueError home.views.signup in my django program

Tags: django-views, httpresponse, valueerror, django-errors

I am trying to create a registration form and store values in database, And i am able to store data in database successfully but i am getting error like this.
please someone tell me what i have done wrong in my code.

**Error :**

```
ValueError at /signup

The view home.views.signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup
Django Version:     4.0
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    The view home.views.signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

**Code:**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from home.models import Public
from datetime import datetime

# Create your views here.
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        pass1 = request.POST.get("password1")
        pass2 = request.POST.get("password2")
        user = Public(name= name, email= email, password= pass1, date= datetime.today())
        if pass1 == pass2:
            user.save()
        else:
            dictionary = {"error": "Password and Confirm password is not match"}
            return render(request, 'signup.html', dictionary)
    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Comment: In case `pass1 == pass2`, then your view does not return anything.

Comment: I didn't even notice it. thank you!